# Transposing columns to rows in Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I currently have a one row settings column in Postgres with each column representing a setting:

```
setting1 | setting2 | setting3 | ...
------------------------------------
true     | false    | 17       | ...
```

I need to transpose this in to a table with key / value rows:

```
key      | value
----------------
setting1 | true
setting2 | false
setting3 | 17
...      | ...
```

I've seen similar questions here, but not this exact problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to avoid enumerating the columns in the query, it can be done with the [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) extension:

```
SELECT (each(hstore(tablename.*))).* FROM tablename;
```

Note that the values are casted to the `text` type.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm runnig 8.4 which doesn't have hStore module installed

Comment: It's available in 8.4 as a contrib module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/hstore.html